# WooCommerce changing "SSSSS" text-based ratings to default Star-ratings

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, review

For those who know WooCommerce, this may seem like a simple fix. Well, I am totally stumped...

My theme overwrites WooCommerce's star-rating system with an ugly "progress bar" style ratings system. First, I worked on getting rid of this (successfully) and switched it to text based ratings such as "4 out of 5".

Next, I used a ton of CSS taken from another WooCommerce website to change the "4 out of 5" on the individual **product pages**, however I am absolutely stumped on the overall **shop page**.

Here's my shop page: thebrains timulator.net/shop
Here's what the original "progress bars" looked like: http://demo.woothemes.com/function/shop/ (see "Castillo Hat")

Here's the code I was able to implement to change the individual product pages from the textual ratings to stars:

```
.woocommerce div.product .woocommerce-product-rating {
    margin-bottom: 1.618em;
}
.woocommerce .woocommerce-product-rating:after, .woocommerce .woocommerce-product-rating:before {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
.woocommerce .woocommerce-product-rating .star-rating {
    margin: .5em 4px 0 0;
    float: left;
}
.woocommerce .star-rating {
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    height: 1em;
    line-height: 1;
    font-size: 1em;
    width: 5.4em;
    font-family: star;
}
.woocommerce .star-rating:before {
    content: "\73\73\73\73\73";
    color: #d3ced2;
    float: left;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    font-family = "star";
}
.woocommerce .star-rating span {
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 1.5em;
    font-family = "star";
}
.woocommerce .star-rating span:before {
    content: "\53\53\53\53\53";
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    font-family: star;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Once the above code was implemented, my shop page changed from the "5 out of 5" text to S's, which is GREAT! (so I thought) because that's actually what WooCommerce uses for to show star-ratings! Uppercase and lower case S's relate to the filled and unfilled star ratings.

However, no matter how I try to tailor the above code to my Shop page, I cannot crack the code. Still stuck with S's...

Any suggestions?

**EDIT** I was able to get the S's on the shop page to convert to stars by removing the "//Disable Woocommerce styles" code located at the top of this file: wp-content/themes/function/includes/integrations/woocommerce/woocommerce.php 
However, removing it screwed up the look of my product pages...

```
<?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;

global $woo_options;

add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );

// Disable WooCommerce styles
if ( version_compare( WOOCOMMERCE_VERSION, '2.1' ) >= 0 ) {
    // WooCommerce 2.1 or above is active
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_enqueue_styles', '__return_false' );
} else {
    // WooCommerce less than 2.1 is active
    define( 'WOOCOMMERCE_USE_CSS', false );
}

// Load WooCommerce stylsheet
if ( ! is_admin() ) { add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'woo_load_woocommerce_css', 20 ); }

if ( ! function_exists( 'woo_load_woocommerce_css' ) ) {
    function woo_load_woocommerce_css () {
        wp_register_style( 'woocommerce', esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() . '/includes/integrations/woocommerce/css/woocommerce.css' ) );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'woocommerce' );
    } // End woo_load_woocommerce_css()
}
```

Any further suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

font-family = "star"

change to;

font-family = "fontawesome"

Changing the so called "stars" to the actual font "fontawesome" worked for me, now stars show.  I couldn't find the font "stars".

Except the numbers to call the stars, I use '\f005\f005\f005\f005\f005' for them to show.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add a custom post class that you can use to distinguish your CSS and make it more specific than your theme's CSS.

```
add_filter( 'post_class', 'so_43142741_post_class', 10, 2 );
function so_43142741_post_class( $classes, $post_id ){
    if( 'product' == get_post_type( $post_id ) ){
        $classes[] = 'use-star-ratings';
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

Then your CSS would look like:

```
.woocommerce div.product.use-star-rating .woocommerce-product-rating {
    margin-bottom: 1.618em;
}
```

**EDIT** It appears that your theme's custom `woocommerce.css` doesn't have any font-face declarations.

I'd recommend copying all the WooCommerce star fonts into a `fonts` folder in your theme and then adding the font-face declaration to your child theme's CSS.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'star';
    src: url('fonts/star.eot');
    src: url('fonts/star.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/star.woff') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/star.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('fonts/star.svg#star') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Alternatively, you could sort out the relative paths from your theme to the WooCommerce plugin folder but this is probably easier.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I'm not familiar with custom post classes, can you explain that a little bit? Are you suggesting I try placing that  filter in my functions.php and the CSS in my Child theme's style.css?

Comment: You can read about [`post_class()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class) in the codex. And yes, the PHP filter goes in your `functions.php` and the CSS in your stylesheet.

Comment: Hmm that didn't seem to work either.. I'm not sure why it's stuck producing the S's on the shop page!

Comment: I just updated my question with some additional information that I think may be helpful, I think I'm getting closer...

Comment: Well I don't know exactly what the CSS should be, but the `.use-star-rating` class will help you make your rule more specific. If you are displaying SSSs that may mean you aren't loading the "star" font-family. Also, while debugging this you should disable whatever is minifying all your CSS into one massive file.

Comment: That's what I'm starting to wonder too, if the star font isn't loading on the shop page for some reason. Is there a way to force it? Yeah, I'm not enough of a developer to know what would be minifying all my css into one file, I didn't even know it was all in one file.. If this could be a caching plugin (I have seen minification options in them) I removed and completely scraped my files of them a while ago, but still see trace effects.

Comment: If you're using a caching plugin, it's probably best to disable that while developing/working on this issue. Also your theme is loading it's own [`woocommerce.css`](http://thebrainstimulator.net/wp-content/themes/function/includes/integrations/woocommerce/css/woocommerce.css?) and it doesn't include any `@font-face` declarations, so the star font is *not* loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I just checked the page over the browser devtools > console. Two plugin-bugs were shown, plus the type issue with the star-font. I just deleted the two plugins and the bug was fixed. I think it was the "hummingbird"-plugin, the other one was a whishlist-tool.